# pwrite and write from the result ioprofile for the MYSQL

Tags: mysql, linux-kernel

I checked the IO activities for the MYSQL by ioprofile , and found binlog used most of the write system call, however transaction log use the most of write type pwrite system call, my question is why binlog  use most of write system call, however pwrite  for transaction log?

```
 total      pread       read     pwrite      write      fsync       open      lseek filename
  3027          0        549          0       2478          0          0          0 /data/mysql/XXX-bin.048425
  1848          0          0       1820          0         28          0          0 /data/mysql/ib_logfile1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two operations are essentially equivalent except that `pwrite` accepts a 4th arg for position, while `write` implicitly writes data at the handle's current offset pointer.

The binlog is almost always written by appending data to the end.

The redo log is more like a ring buffer, typically fixed in size, where the writes wrap around from near the end back to near the beginning.

> The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it writes into a given position without changing the file pointer.
>
> The first three arguments to `pwrite()` are the same as `write()` with the addition of a fourth argument offset for the desired position inside the file.
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/3/pwrite

Comment: Thank you Michael, I got it now.